# Python Httpx lib error: h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: can't handle event type ConnectionClosed when role=SERVER and state=SEND_RESPONSE

Tags: python, httpx

Hello guys i am trying to send a request in Python using

```py
with httpx.Client(cookies=cookies, headers=headers, proxies="http://username:password@ip:port", timeout=30) as client:
```

But it is giving me the following error

```
h11._util.RemoteProtocolError: can't handle event type ConnectionClosed when role=SERVER and state=SEND_RESPONSE
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I was using an older version of the library thats why it was not working, I tried reinstalling it and it was working fine again